# How can I keep line breaks from Excel to Word?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have this code

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim word_fichier As Document
Dim MaFeuille As Worksheet
Dim nb_lines As Integer

    For i = 14 To nb_lines
        With word_fichier.Range.Find
            .Text = MaFeuille.Cells(i, 1)
            .Replacement.Text = MaFeuille.Cells(i, 2)
            .Execute Replace:=2
        End With
    Next i
```

This code is good but if I have a cell like that

```
hello
i am the
annoying string
```

The `.replacement.text` dont keep line breaks.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Try replacing the Lf with CrLf: `.Replacement.Text = Replace$(MaFeuille.Cells(i, 2), vbLf, vbCrLf)`

Comment: I wrote it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel uses just a line feed `vbLf` in its cells.

If you want a real line break in Word you need to convert that into `vbCrLf` for a paragraph break <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `vbVerticalTab` for a manual line break <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
.Replacement.Text = Replace$(MaFeuille.Cells(i, 2), vbLf, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: «If you want a real line break in Word you need to convert that into vbCrLf» No, that creates *paragraph* breaks in Word. *Line* breaks are created via Chr(11).

Comment: @macropod Well good point, technically more precise. I made it clear in my answer to show the difference. Thx for pointing out.